# Exclude only specific folder in tar command

Tags: shell, tar, archive

I want to tar a directory that looks like this:

```
dir
└── workspace
└── node_modules
└── subfolder
    └── workspace
    └── node_modules
    └── other_folder
```

I want to exclude **all** folders named `node_modules` and exclude the top level folder called `workspace`, but no sub folders called `workspace`.
So what I want to end up with is this:

```
dir
└── subfolder
    └── workspace
    └── other_folder
```

I'm running this command: `tar -czf ./output.tar.gz --exclude=node_modules --exclude=./workspace dir/.`

But it's removing **all** folders called workspace *and* node_modules, so I instead end up with this:

```
dir
└── subfolder
    └── other_folder
```

How do I remove only the specific workspace folder that I want, and not all folders with the same name?

Comment: So for anything more complicated, use [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to create the list of files to compress. Then pass this list to tar, preferably with `xargs -0` or similar method.

Comment: The actual folder structure is a lot more complicated than this and includes a large number of files and folders. I would like to exclude and not include, since I'm only excluding two folders, and the exclude flag is there and can take a pattern, as far as I understand

Answer (score 2):

For the required case, possible to use tar excludes:

- `--exclude dir/./folder` -- apply to folder directly under dir
- `--exclude folder` -- will exclude folder anywhere in the tree

Should be possible to use:

```
tar -czf ./output.tar.gz --exclude=node_modules --exclude=dir/./workspace dir/.
```

Of course possible to use `--files-from`, and to generate the list using another tool. This is usually preferred when the list could be large number of files, vs using `xargs`.

```
find dir/. -type f ... | tar cvz ./output.tar.gz -T-
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` has many, many, many options for including, excluding paths, files, directories, generally filtering options however you want to.

For your case I think it would be:

```
# exclude all folders named node_modules
# exclude the top level folder called workspace
# but no sub folders called workspace
find dir -type f \
    -not -regex '.*/node_modules/.*' -a \
    -not -regex 'dir/workspace/.*' \
    -exec tar -czf ./output.tar.gz {} +
```

You may prefer instead of `-exec` for example `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 tar -czf ./output.tar.gz`. I think the best would be `find ... -print0 | tar -czf ./output.tar.gz --null -T -` as it will not fail if there are too many files, ie. too many arguments to pass to `tar`, I think.

I recreated `dir` directory with:

```
while read l; do
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$l")"
    touch "$l"
done <<EOF
dir/workspace/1.txt
dir/node_modules/2.txt
dir/subfolder/workspace/3.txt
dir/subfolder/node_modules/4.txt
dir/subfolder/other_folder/5.txt
EOF
```

then [tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ShorttermTealBot) and the `tar -tf ./output.tar.gz` prints:

```
dir/subfolder/workspace/3.txt
dir/subfolder/other_folder/5.txt
```